# Non-prop attribute label not working whilst style does

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a custom component called PasswordInput, defined as

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
    prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
    :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
    @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPassword: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and used like this

```
<password-input
  label="Password"
  style="background-color:red"
></password-input>
```

However, although the style is passed to the route element, the label doesn't seem to work, as seen here, [image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Bind*** all `attributes` to `v-text-field` that you are applying on
>   the `password-input` in the parent component.

```
<v-text-field
 v-bind="$attrs" // <-- Here
 :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
 prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
 :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
 @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
/>
```

Comment: you are adding attribute ie. label to `password-input` & v-text-field has no idea what is label!,  you can access all the attributes of a component by `$attrs` or if you just want to access label `$attrs.label`, so we bound all attributes ie. $attr to `v-text-field` & hence label also got bound to it, which `v-text-field` as per Vuetify doc eventually uses as a prop to display on the dom.